# Update HTML element after append

Tags: javascript, dom

I am facing the following problem: I have a class which creates an HTML Element and adds it to the DOM.

I want to be able to change the element after adding the HTML element to the DOM. Is it possible to make a modification to an already added DOM element?

See example below:

- I create the class TextNode
- TextNode generates an HTML Element
- I add the HTML element to my HTML body
- I change the text and regenerate the HTML Element in TextNode

However, the HTMLElement in the DOM does not respond to the change. Is there no binding between the Javascript element and the DOM?

```js
class TextNode {
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
  render() {
    const node = document.createElement('p');
    node.innerText = this.text;
    this.node = node;
  }
}

const node = new TextNode('Hello')
node.render();
document.querySelector('body').append(node.node);

node.text = 'Hello there!';
node.render();
```

See a live demo [here](https://playcode.io/1015999)

I've tried looking on StackOverflow for solutions, but can't find anything.

I expect to be able to update my DOM element after a change in its class, without adding the element all over again in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

No longer needed, I realize that I am creating a completely new HTML element with the render function.

I have now added an update function which modifies the existing HTML element, and it now works properly.

```js
class TextNode {
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
  render() {
    const node = document.createElement('p');
    node.innerText = this.text;
    this.node = node;
  }
  update() {
    this.node.innerText = this.text;
  }
}

const node = new TextNode('Hello')
node.render();
document.querySelector('body').append(node.node);

node.text = 'Hello there!';
node.update();
```

Comment: There is a stack snippet tool you can use `<>` to create runable snippets. I've edited your question and answer with it.